# Can I use multiple ADO.Net Entity Models in a single ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sqlexception

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC web application & using ADO.NET Entity Data Model (Entity Framework) as A model. In one view, I want to autocomplete the table column values from other database which is located in another server as B model.

Here one thing, the tables for controller which I am using have the same name in both the models A & B as `Employee` table. So, I have created a new folder and added Entity Framework as model B in that folder.

In local host it is working fine. But where as coming to the production, I get an error

> Login failed for user xxxxx**

I have cross checked all the solutions like changes in `web.config` file and all. No solution found to resolve my error.

So, here's my question: can I use multiple ADO.NET entity models in a single ASP.NET MVC project?

If yes, how to do that? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Absolute answer will be appreciated

Error:

[image: Login Failed for User abcd].

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple models, but that error message seems unrelated.  Looks like SQL Server permissions.  The following may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255223/login-failed-for-user-sa-asp-net-mvc-page

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use multiple models but I think this error might have been caused by error in connection string please check your connection string